# Wait message with full refresh in xpages

Tags: xpages, message, wait

I am developing an application on xpages and would like to put a wait message while there is an ongoing processing. There are several articles that indicate how to do, but this only functional with partial update. I need the message, preferably with lock and an animated gif to work with the full update.

Comment: Hi Marcus! Can you add some code to show what you've tried so far?

Comment: I tried the links below

Comment: I tried the links below:

(https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=standby-dialog-custom-control)

(http://lotusnotus.com/lotusnotus_en.nsf/dx/xpages-tip-a-modal-waiting-dialog-for-background-processes..htm)

(https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Loading_Images_and_page_Masking_on_an_X-Page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was use the technique described in the link below, from an article by Brad Balassaits. In the various techniques mentioned, I implemented the one that inserts the waiting animated gif into the triggered button. From the techniques suggested and researched this was the one that would least impact when there are changes of adjustments in the application.

[Brad Balassaiti article](https://xcellerant.net/2014/03/10/dojo-in-xpages-11-using-loading-images-to-improve-perceived-responsiveness/)

Answer (score 2):

Problem is that a full refresh will reload the page, to get this working you need to load the page inside an iframe and place the standby code in the top page.

If you do something you need to call parent.window.dothestandby()
and in onload on the page inside the iframe call parent.window.hidestandy()

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this NotesIn9 video by David Leedy and watch from 5 minutes and see if it helps:

http://www.notesin9.com/2016/02/19/notesin9-188-adding-a-please-wait-to-xpages/

Comment: I've already seen this video, the code is based on one of the links I listed. Only works for partial update. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure? The first part of the video talks about partial refresh, but from the 5 min mark it talks about page load?

Comment: I saw yes, but it is not exactly what I want, besides that part treat the message in the load of xpage and use a panel where the content is placed, and whose refresh is partial. I need to put a wait message when clicking a button with full update. I will try to adpate this technique to my need. I actually found a [solution] (https://xcellerant.net/2014/03/10/dojo-in-xpages-11-using-loading-images-to-improve-perceived-responsiveness/) that met my need even though I could not put the animated gif in the center of the screen.

Thank you very much!